# How to make an http.put request correctly with ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, http, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am making a request put but it returns an error, I do not know that I am doing wrong

> "@angular/http": "4.1.3"

```
this.http.put( url, JSON.stringify(body)).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log('the consultation was completed I think with success:', [data]);
     },
    err => {
        console.log("query error: ", err);
    }
)
```

The error is the following OPTIONS net :: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and the console.log says the error is:

```
Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}
    headers : Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)}
    ok : false
    status : 0
    statusText : ""
    type : 3
    url : null
    _body : ProgressEvent
    bubbles : false
    cancelBubble : false
    cancelable : false
    composed : false
    currentTarget : XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__eventTasks: Array(0), __zone_symbol__xhrTask: t, readyState: 4, __zone_symbol__xhrListener: ƒ, …}
    defaultPrevented : false
    eventPhase : 0
    isTrusted : true
    lengthComputable : false
    loaded : 0
    path : []
    returnValue : true
    srcElement : XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__eventTasks: Array(0), __zone_symbol__xhrTask: t, readyState: 4, __zone_symbol__xhrListener: ƒ, …}
    target : XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__eventTasks: Array(0), __zone_symbol__xhrTask: t, readyState: 4, __zone_symbol__xhrListener: ƒ, …}
    timeStamp : 30986.310000000005
    total : 0
    type : "error"
    __proto__ : ProgressEvent
    __proto__ : Body
```

If I delete the method .subscribe() does not output any errors, but check if the record of my table in the database was modified and is not modified.

The post requests work perfectly, it is with the put is that I have problems

Comment: if you use postman to hit the same endpoint do you get data?

Comment: What version of Angular's Http client are you using? What is the value from the 'body' parameter - is this an object or is a 'stringified' object? Does the request reach your backend/API (you can check this via logs from the API app)?

Comment: "@angular/http": "4.1.3", body is JSON.stringify(body)

Comment: "The post requests work perfectly" -- for the same URL, does the POST work perfectly, while the PUT will meet error? `OPTIONS net :: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` indicate a preflight CORS error.